# Improve mysql performance over network

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, networking

I have server with Centos and mysql and another client with Windows 7 that updates the server ovet the network.

Is there any way performance could be improved? For example, to update 100,000k records locally, it takes like 1minute, to do it over the network, it takes 15 minutes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql` client takes a `--compress` switch that will compress traffic over the network.  It sounds like this might be helpful for you.  Information about the C# driver version is documented under [UseCompression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html).

Comment: do I add `Compress=true;` to my connection string? I added it, don't see improvement.

Comment: Latency might be killing your performance.  You may be able to write your updates as multi-inserts and use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update the values.  Alternatively, you can use `AllowBatch=true;` and send multiple `UPDATE` statements at one time.